# renderAs pdf is not working with the footer at the bottom

Tags: visualforce, css, html

I'm new in Salesforce but I have a quote that I need to show as a PDF with a header and a footer but just in the last page. Actually is working with renderAs="pdf" But is not showing the footer at the bottom of the page, it show it where it end (it could be at the beggining, middle or end). However if I don't write renderAs="pdf", it works fine but just as HTML page.

I made a simple dummy that you can edit writting and deleting the renderAs="pdf" to see the issue.

Any help would be really apprecciate it.

This is the dummy:

CSS:

```
<style> 
    html,body {margin:0;padding:0;height:100%;}
#wrapper {min-height:100%;position:relative;}
#header {padding:10px;background:#5ee;}
#content {padding:10px;padding-bottom:80px;   /* Height of the footer element */}
#footer {width:100%;height:80px;position:absolute;content : "My Footer on right Side";bottom:0;left:0;background:#ee5;}
    </style>
```

PAGE:

All the HTML code inside apex code:

```
<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" readOnly="true">

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="header"></div>
            <div id="content"></div>
            <div id="footer"> content : "My Footer on right Side";</div>
        </div>
    </body>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: All the HTML code inside apex code:     

<apex:page renderAs="pdf" applyHtmlTag="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false" readOnly="true" >
 <body>
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="header"></div>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <div id="footer"> content : "My Footer on right Side";</div>
</div>
</body>
</apex:page>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I strongly suspect the problem is with your CSS. When you renderAs as PDF, you're essentially "printing" the HTML page just like you would on a printer. SF's PDF engine only supports CSS 2.1, not CSS 3.

Your current CSS for the footer looks like the following:

```
#footer {width:100%;height:80px;position:absolute;content : "My Footer on right Side";bottom:0;left:0;background:#ee5;}
```

I think you need to define your header and footer layout for the page in an `@page` using something like the following:

```
@page {
    margin : 10pt .5in .5in .5in; // use whatever values are appropriate
    @top-center {
        content : "My Header";
     }
    @bottom-right {
        content : "My Footer on Right Side";
        color : #808080; // optional as this can be in your def for content
    }
}
```

Once you have the above, you can define the header and footer using CSS 2.1 compatible properties.

For more on this, see [CSS 2.1 Paged Media](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/page.html#page-intro) and for more information on the PDF rendering engine Salesforce is using see: [Flying Saucer](https://code.google.com/p/flying-saucer/).

Comment: Thanks for your explanation I already used this style that you recommended and it works but just an always footer or header, not for the last page. I use for the last page @page:last {} but it seems that doesn't work with salesforce PDF render.

Comment: You might try something like `< div style="page-break-after: always;" >
your content here
< /div>` for the one that has the footer in it. The other thing is that your original CSS has the footer positioned as absolute. You might want to avoid that and allow it to be relative to see if that changes your results on the last page. The other thing I'll say is that Tables are generally preferred over Divs and might give you better results with the last page, but you'll also have more break before and break after issues with table content.

Comment: Thanks a lot for helping me, but, it doesn't work. It should work with @page:last{} but is not working, I suppose have to be with Salesforce because  if create the same page just as HTML it works without any problem.

Comment: There's often a huge difference between what "should" work and what does work. I recommend you convert to tables if this feature is important to you. Also ensure you're using CSS 2.1 compatible CSS. Your original CSS appeared to contain some CSS level 3.

Comment: Thanks for your help...Maybe is important that salesforce update their compatibly with CSS 3. I will figure it out how can I solve this, because if I don't render it as PDF it works as it should be.